# Prevent insertion if the records already exist in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am programming for iPhone and i am using SQLITE DB for my app.I have a situation where i want to insert records into the table,only if the records doesn't exist previously.Otherwise the records should not get inserted.

How can i do this?Please any body suggest me a suitable query for this.

Thank you one and all,

Answer (score 11):

Looking at SQLite's INSERT page http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html.

You can do it using the following syntax

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tablename ....
```

*Example*

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tablename(id, value, data) VALUES(2, 4562, 'Sample Data');
```

*Note :* You need to have a KEY on the table columns which uniquely identify a row. It is only if a duplicate KEY is tried to be inserted that `INSERT OR IGNORE` will not insert a new row.

In the above example if you have a `KEY` on `id`, then another row with `id = 2` will not be inserted.
If you have a `KEY` only on `id and value` then a combination of `id = 2 and value = 4562` will cause a new row not be inserted.

In short there *must be a key to uniquely identify a ROW* only then will the Database know there is a duplicate which SHOULD NOT Be allowed.

*Otherwise* if you do not have a KEY you would need to go the `SELECT` and then check if a row is already there, route. But here also whichever condition you are using on columns you can add them as a `KEY` to the table and simply use the `INSERT OR IGNORE`

In SQLite it is not possible to ALTER the table and add a constraint like UNIQUE or PRIMAY KEY. For that you need to recreate the table. Look at this FAQ on sqlite.org
http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q11

Comment: Hi Danish,Thanks for your response,Friend i actually know the beginning i got them from few blogs what is after that like "INSERT or IGNORE INTO tablename(col1,col2) values ("10","Hello")....I am really worried about this part......".Can you guide me in this regard?Thanks

Comment: @Sankar It is the same as a normal INSERT Statement, nothing special. But if you want the exact query, I would need to know your table structure. But I have added a generic example to my answer.

Comment: Dhanish thanks,i tried that but its not working it still adds the records which are already present,does any column should be a primary key?

Comment: @Sankar YES you need a Primary Key column. The INSERT OR IGNORE, does not add a new row IF there is a KEY CONFLICT. So you need to add a KEY column, which uniquely identifies your row.

Answer (score 3):

Hello Sankar what you can do is perform a select query with the record you wish to insert and then check the response via SQLite's SQLITE_NOTFOUND flag you can check whether that record already exists or not. If it doesn't exist you can insert it otherwise you skip inserting.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: That would work, but I'm hoping there's less bothersome way to do this ;)