# Is there a way to add a row only if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

Using PHP PDO with SQLite, I can write a PDO call to check if a certain row exists (by checking for the primary key) in the table, and then if it doesn't, write another PDO call to create the row.  But I feel like it should be somehow possible to do in one command… similar to the "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS".  Is there anything like "INSERT ROW IF NOT EXISTS"?

Comment: don;t you think you should check INSERT COMMAND manual

Comment: @MisterMelancholy, I get a PDO error when I try following that answer.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed Then *include* the relevant error (and *show* what was tried which resulted in said error).

Comment: Different approaches discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779823/sqlite-query-to-insert-a-record-if-not-exists and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481161/prevent-insertion-if-the-records-already-exist-in-sqlite?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ...
```

where your table has some constraint (such as a `PRIMARY KEY` column) that will cause a conflict when a row is attempted to be inserted again.

Reference: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html